# Is there any way to get only health related news through news api?

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I am making an app in which I want only health related news..

So,For getting news I am using newsapi.org ..it is giving news of all categories.

But I want only health related news to appear..

Can You help in it?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the keyword: "health"

`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=health&apiKey=API_KEY`

Answer (score 0):

This page `https://newsapi.org/sources` then country and then source can help you do that. For example `http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=rs&category=health&apiKey=API_KEY` but I don't know if `category` works without `country`. If not you can filter countries you want, make several requests and deduplicate by Id or some text matching.

Also there are q attribute.

Also it's seems to have nothing with android and android-studio.